Rendering Preview Images on Timeline of Video Player Issue
I am attempting to have a preview image pop up whenever I hover my cursor over the timeline bar for my react video player. I can see the box pop up properly for wherever I am hovering. However, the preview image itself is not rendering within the box. Below are the relevant snippets of code:
JSContextProvider.tsx:
import { useReducer,useEffect, useRef, ReactNode, } from 'react';
import { JSContext, ContextProps } from './JSContext';
import classes from '../Components/Shows/VideoPlayer/VideoStyles.module.css';

export const JSProvider = ({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) => { 
 const videoRef = useRef<HTMLVideoElement | null>(null);
  const timelineContainerElement = document.querySelector(`.${classes.timelineContainer}`) as HTMLDivElement | null;
  const thumbnailImgElement = document.querySelector(`.${classes.thumbnailImg}`) as HTMLImageElement | null;
  const previewImgElement = document.querySelector(`.${classes.previewImg}`) as HTMLImageElement | null;

  const handleTimelineUpdate = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
    const rect = e.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect();
    const percent = Math.min(Math.max(0, e.clientX - rect.x), rect.width) / rect.width;
    if (!videoRef.current){
      return;
    }
    const previewImgNumber = Math.max(1, Math.floor((percent * videoRef.current?.duration / 10)));
    if (previewImgElement) {

      const previewImgSrc = `../Assets/PreviewImgs/${previewImgNumber}.jpg`;
      previewImgElement.src = previewImgSrc
      if (timelineContainerElement){
        timelineContainerElement.style.setProperty("--preview-position", `${percent}`);
      }
  
      if (state.isScrubbing){
        e.preventDefault();
        if(!thumbnailImgElement || !timelineContainerElement){
          return;
        }
        thumbnailImgElement.src = previewImgSrc
        timelineContainerElement.style.setProperty("--progress-position", `${percent}`);
      }
    }
  }

const contextValue: ContextProps = {
    state,
    dispatch,
    videoRef,  
    handleTimelineUpdate,
  };

return (
    <JSContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
      {children}
    </JSContext.Provider>
  );
}
export default JSProvider;

JSContext.ts:
import { createContext, createRef, } from 'react';
import { JSReducerAction, JSReducerState } from './JSContextProvider';

export type ContextProps = {
  state: JSReducerState;
  dispatch: React.Dispatch<JSReducerAction>;
  handleTimelineUpdate: (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => void,

};

export const JarlStudiosContext = createContext<ContextProps>({
  state: {
  },
  dispatch: () => {},
  videoRef: createRef(),
  handleTimelineUpdate: () => {},
});

VideoStyles.module.css:
.timelineContainer{
    height: 7px;
    margin-inline: .5rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}



.timeline {
    background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, .5);
    height: 3px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.timeline::before{
   content: ""; 
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   right: calc(100% - var(--preview-position) * 100%);
   background-color: rgb(150, 150, 150);
   display: none;
}

.timeline::after{
    content: ""; 
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: calc(100% - var(--progress-position) * 100%);
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    filter: brightness(110%) drop-shadow(0 0 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)) grayscale(10%);
}

.timeline .thumbIndicator {
    --scale: 0;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateX(-50%) scale(var(--scale));
    height: 200%;
    top: -50%;
    left: calc(var(--progress-position) * 100%);
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    filter: brightness(110%) drop-shadow(0 0 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)) grayscale(10%);
    border-radius: 50%;
    aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
}

.timeline .previewImg{
    position: absolute;
    height: 80px;
    aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;
    top: -1rem;
    transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
    left: calc(var(--preview-position) * 100%);
    border-radius: .25rem;
    border: 2px solid white;
    display: none;
}

.thumbnailImg{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
}

.timelineContainer.scrubbing .thumbnailImg{
    display: block;
}

.timelineContainer.scrubbing .previewImg,
.timelineContainer:hover .previewImg{
    display: block;
}

.timelineContainer.scrubbing .timeline::before,
.timelineContainer:hover .timeline::before{
    display: block;
}


.timelineContainer.scrubbing .thumbIndicator,
.timelineContainer:hover .thumbIndicator{
 --scale: 1;
}

.timelineContainer.scrubbing .timeline,
.timelineContainer:hover .timeline{
    height: 100%;
}

TimelineContainer.tsx:
import { useJSContext } from '../../../../Context/UseJSContext';
import classes from '../VideoStyles.module.css';

const TimelineContainer = () => {
    const {state, toggleScrubbing,handleTimelineUpdate} = useJSContext();


  return (
    <div 
    className={`${classes.timelineContainer} ${
      state.isScrubbing === true ? `${classes.isScrubbing}` : ''
    }`} 
    onMouseDown={(e) => {
      toggleScrubbing(e);
    }}
    onMouseUp={(e) => {
      if (state.isScrubbing) {
        toggleScrubbing(e);
      }
    }}
    onMouseMove={handleTimelineUpdate}
    >
         <div className={classes.timeline}>
            <img  className={classes.previewImg} />
            <div  className={classes.thumbIndicator}></div>
         </div> 
    </div>
  )
}

export default TimelineContainer

Folder File Structure:

I am ultimately trying to get that 1.jpg file to render within the preview image box that pops up above my timeline bar whenever I hover over it. For further context, I am attempting to create a react version from this video:
How To Create The YouTube Video Player
and this github of the code:
YoutubeVideoPlayerClone
